# Accessing the output of a Bash pipe with 'read'

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pipe some data from a Bash pipe into a Bash variable using the read command, like this:

```
$ echo "Alexander the Grape" | read quot
$ echo $quot
$
```

But quot is empty.
Some Googling revealed that this is not a bug; it's an intended feature of Bash. (Section [E5 in the FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ).)

But when I tried the same thing in zsh, it worked. (Ditto for ksh.)
Is there any way to make this work in Bash? I really don't want to have to type:

```
$ quot=$(echo "Alexander the Grape")
```

Especially for long commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For additional reading on this subject, see [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

There are a bunch of ways to do variable assignments in Bash:

```
var=$(command)
read var <<< $(command)
read var <<< EOF
$(command)
EOF
printf -v var "%s" $(command)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. Not what I was looking for, but these are very interesting alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

```
read quot < <(echo "Alexander the Grape")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to create a command inside a variable and then run it by specifying the variable? Then don't. run the command as it is.

Comment: Actually, I'm parsing really large numbers (1000+ digits). I wanted to store it into a variable because it got unwieldy after a while.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.  If you prefer the behaviour of a different shell, switch to that shell.  Market forces. :)