# How to merge ls commands colors with the output of find or du?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, shell-script, zsh

I have a simple alias to list the size of files&folders in cwd.

( including dotfiles in this case , ignoring zero sizes )

```
du -sh .[!.]* * | sort -hr | grep -v '^0'
```

which can be achieved aswell with find:

```
find .[!.]* * -maxdepth 0 -exec du -sh {} \; | sort -hr | grep -v '^0'
```

example output:

```
// .ssh & .byobu are folders - .zsh* are files
// currently not able to distinguish them by type

... 
32K     .zshrc
25K     .ssh
20K     .zcompdump
19K     .byobu
...
```

**How can i color the files/directories in the output matching the ls colors?** ( LS_COLORS )

Comment: I can't see why this doesn't work - it does with a `print`, but gets mangled with the `system`:  `du -sh .[!.]* * | sort -hr | grep -v '^0'  | awk '{print $1;system( "ls -d --color '$2'") }'`

Comment: this definitely points to the right direction... The output is colored ( all with ls's dir color ) ... but all files/folders are transformed to "/n." . thanks for your efforts - i realize the solution will probably be some tricky sed/awk !! :)

Comment: you can also use the --color option available for grep .... 
  eg : ` find . -iname "t*" | du -sh * | grep stuff --color=auto`

Comment: Thanks - i already have grep aliased to `grep --color=auto` ... grep will highlight a *search string/pattern* in the output ... but not divide between files & folders in the output using the LS_COLORS. Thanks for the hint anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `zsh` script parses `$LS_COLORS`. It needs only a `stat` call on every file and hence is much faster than the solution at the bottom, which calls `ls` for every file. And it handles files with spaces correctly. (`\n` or `\t` are still *not* allowed in file names)

However, the implementation is not complete. I only included colors for different filetypes which can be identified by the first character of the file mode string (e. g. `lrwxrwxrwx` for a symbolic link) or by the file extension. That means, that world-writable permissions, suid or sticky bits are not colored specially. To include those also should be straight forward.

`source` the following and use the new shell function `duc` for a colored `du` output:

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

function duc() {

  emulate zsh 
  setopt no_nomatch interactivecomments           # no_nomatch is necessary, to prevent error in "do .* *" if there are no dotfiles

  typeset -a aline
  typeset -A lscols
  local dircols acolor

  for i (${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}) {                    # split $LS_COLORS at ":"
    aline=(${(s:=:)i})                            # split every entry at "="
    lscols+=(${${aline[1]}/*.} ${aline[2]})       # load every entry into the associative array $lscols
  }

  duout=$(du -sh .* * 2> /dev/null | grep -v '^0' | sort -hr)
  for i (${(f)duout}) {                           # split output of "du" at newlines
    aline=(${(ps:\t:)i})                          # split every entry at \t
    zstat -s +mode -A atype ${aline[2]}           # determine mode (e.g. "drwx------") of file ${aline[2]}
    case ${${atype[1]}[1]} in                     # ${${atype[1]}[1]} is the first character of the file mode
      b)   acolor=$lscols[bd] ;;
      c|C) acolor=$lscols[cd] ;;
      d)   acolor=$lscols[di] ;;
      l)   acolor=$lscols[ln] ;;
      p)   acolor=$lscols[pi] ;;
      s)   acolor=$lscols[so] ;;
      -)   acolor=${lscols[${${aline[2]}:e}]};      # ${${aline[2]}:e} is the current file extention
           [[ -z $acolor ]] && acolor=$lscols[fi]   # unrecognized extention
           [[ -z $acolor ]] && acolor=00            # sometimes "fi" isn't set in $LS_COLORS, so fall back to normal color
           ;;
      *)   acolor=00 ;;
    esac
    print -n -- "${aline[1]}\t"        # print size (taken from du output)
    print -n "\\e[4${acolor}m"         # activate color
    print -n ${aline[2]}               # print file name
    print "\\e[0m"                     # deactivate color
  }
}
```

---

This is my old script, also for `zsh`. It probably unnecessarily complex and is really slow, as for every file a single `ls` command is issued:

```
du_colored() {
  typeset -a duout
  duout=($(du -sh .* * | sort -hr | grep -v '^0'))
  for i ({1..$#duout..2}) {
    print -n "${duout[$i]}\t"
    ls -d --color ${duout[$(($i+1))]}
  }
}
```

- the `.*` in `zsh` will **not** match `.` or `..`, but files like `..foo` which will be missed with `.[!.]*`
- `typeset -a` declares an array
- the for loops aver the array, `$i` takes values from 1 onwards in steps of 2

**Warning**: This will break badly when there are files with *blanks*... I don't have a better idea at the moment.

Comment: +1 for this being the first almost working solution. executing ls for every file seems overkill. simply matching one ls -a --colors ( outputting the colors ) against the second string ( folder/filename without color ) in the output of du would be more performant. trying to achieve it but can't find a sufficient way yet :/

Comment: `ls -a --color | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"` removes the colors - now how can we replace the `du` output with the colored output of `ls -a --color` ? :)

Comment: @nifr: I added another script, that parses `$LS_COLORS` directly. This runs much faster than my yesterday's long-after-midnight hack as it only needs to stat every file instead of running `ls`.

Comment: Nice addition thank you - i hacked together a solution for bash yesterday in a night session - will post it below, maybe you can review it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i came up with for bash - uses pv to show the output progress

```
folder_size (){
  # read ls --color output into ls_colored_array 
  # thereby remove symlinks (@) and remove (/ and *) from folders and files

  ls -AF --color | grep -v @ | sed s'/[/\,*]$//'| xargs -n1 -L1 | read -d '\n' -r -a ls_colored_array

  # - loop over the array and issue du -sh for every element
  # - exchange du's ouput with ls's 
  # - run loop through pv with line option and
  #    size set to array-length showing progress
  # - finally sort the output using sort

  for i in "${ls_colored_array[@]}"; do
    echo -n "${i}" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | xargs -n1 -0 du -sh | awk -v i="$i" '{ printf "%-10s ", $1; $1=""; print i }'
  done | pv -pls"${#ls_colored_array[@]}" | sort -hr
}
```

Script can now be turned into a one-liner ... but i'll improve the function by adding flags for i.e. 10 biggest files/folders or folders only.

Comment: This is a nice solution, especially that part with the progress bar, +1 for that `:)` However, I had to change the read line to `read -d '\n' -r -a ls_colored_array <<< $(ls -AF --color | grep -v @ | sed s'/[/\,*]$//'| xargs -n1 -L1)` to get it working in plain bash (related: http://superuser.com/questions/173337/accessing-the-output-of-a-bash-pipe-with-read). Unfortunately this script breaks on blanks in file names. (I suppose you need to use a counter to access all the `$ls_colored_array` elements instead of passing the array directly to the for loop).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

paste <(du --apparent-size --all --human-readable --max-depth=1 2>/dev/null |
    sed 's/\s.*//') \
    <(ls --color=always -1 --almost-all -U) | sort --human-numeric-sort
```

The main command here is `paste`, it will join the outputs of `ls` and `du` horizontally.

`du` will output each line something like this:

```
147291    ./.config
```

`sed 's/\s.*//` will delete everything after and including the first space, i.e.     `./.config` since we aren't interested in the non-colored forms of the listed entries' names.
The trick here is to make `ls` output the contents of of the directory the same way as `du` so that we can effortlessly join each entry with its corresponding size. We can do that with the help of `-1` (which lists entries vertically instead of horizontally), `-U` (which lists entries in directory order, just like `du`, instead of alphabetically) and `--almost-all` (which lists hidden directories/files too but leaves out `.` and `..` as opposed to `--all`) and of course `--color=always`. For `du`, `--all` is needed to make it process both files (including hidden ones) and directories instead of just directories, and `--max-depth=1` stops `du` from operating on sub-directories (just like `find`'s `-maxdepth 1`)

So, to answer the question, only the following is needed:

```
paste <(du --all --max-depth=1 | sed 's/\s.*//') \
    <(ls --color=always -1 --almost-all -U)
```

As for the other optional arguments:

- `--apparent-size` makes `du` print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage (my preference)
- `--human-readable` prints human readable sizes
- `2>/dev/null` filters out any `permission denied` errors if you tried running `du` in a restricted directory e.g. `/var`
- `sort --human-numeric-sort` sorts sizes in descending order,  `--human-numeric-sort` is needed if `--human-readable`is passed to `du`

Comment: (1) We prefer answers that have some explanation or other commentary.  (2) Why not just do `sed 's/\s.*//'`?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I spotted the question and I tried answering in a hurry. And yes,
`sed 's/\s.*//'` is more concise and efficient than `sed 's/\.\/.*//;
s/\s\+$//'`(I don't even know what I was thinking when I wrote that). My answer's been edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Combining some of the above answers with oh-my-zshell on a Mac provided me sizes, colorized directory names and plain text file names sorted to output the 10 largest files/directories:

```bash
paste <(du -cks *) <(ls --color=always -1) | sort -nr | head | awk '{print $1 "  " $3}'
```

Explanation: 
`du` for disk use `-c:grand total -k: 1Kb blocks -s: entry` for each file;
`ls` to grab the color for directories;
`paste` to combine both of the above outputs;
`sort -nr`: numeric reverse sort;
`head`: outputs largest files/directories;
`awk`: to output only the first column (size) and the 3rd column (file/colorized directory name)